# Code won't validate

Tags: javascript, json, lint

Json lint won't validate my code. Do you know why?

This is the updated code. It is one object which includes schools and online education.

```
var education ={
    "schools": [
      {
        "name": "University of Hertfordshire",
        "location": "Hertfordshir e, UK",
        "degree": "Masters",
        "Major": ["Computer Science"],
        "graduation": "2017 (expected)"
      },
       {
        "name": "University of Applied Sciences",
        "location": "Jena, German",
        "degree": "Diplom",
        "Major": ["Business Administration and Information Systems"],
        "graduation": "2010"
    }
  ]
} ,

    "onlineCourses": [
    {
        "title": "Javascript Syntax",
        "school": "Udacity",
        "dates": "May 2016"
    }]
}
```

Comment: The two objects are not part of a parent node. What do you think the comma, between the two objects, is doing? You have to wrap the objects in an array, `[ {}, {} ]`, for the JSON to make sense. Also, the validator you linked to tells you that it expects an EOF (end of file), but encountered a `,` character. Researching the error message some more would most likely have given you a solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "schools": [{
        "name": "University of Hertfordshire",
        .....
    }, {
        "name": "University of Applied Sciences",
        .....
    }]
}, {
    "onlinecourse": [{
        "title": "Javascript Syntax",
        ....
    }]
}
```

you've got 2 objects dangling here that need to be inside `[]` like

```
 [
  {
        "schools": [{
            "name": "University of Hertfordshire"
             .....
        }, {
            "name": "University of Applied Sciences"
             ....
        }]
    }, {
        "onlinecourse": [{
            "title": "Javascript Syntax"
          .....
        }]
    }
]
```

**EDIT**

in your updated code

```
{
    "schools": [
      {
        "name": "University of Hertfordshire"
        .....
      },
       {
        "name": "University of Applied Sciences"   
         .....   
    } ]
} ,

    "onlineCourses": [
    {
        "title": "Javascript Syntax"
         ......
    }]
}
```

notice the `}` after `schools` array is acting as a end of object marker and there is no `{` before `onlinecourse` to suggest to the parser that `onlinecourse` is part of another object and bcoz of all that mess , the parser thinks you have multiple root elements. Here's the solution:

```
[      // json is contained in an array bcoz there are multiple objects 
 {
    "schools": [
      {
        "name": "University of Hertfordshire"
      },
       {
        "name": "University of Applied Sciences"   
       }
     ]
   },{    // the `}` your code was missing

    "onlineCourses": [
    {
        "title": "Javascript Syntax" 
    }]
  }
]   // end of json array
```

ofcourse take the comments out of json when validating as they are not allowed in json.

Comment: ohhh sorry mate. i did not send the complete code through. They are actually parf an ot opbject called education. see updated code above

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a stray `}` after the `]` that closes off the schools array.

```
{
    "schools": [
    ....  
  ]
```

STRAY ==> }

```
 ,    
 "onlineCourses": [
    {
        "title": "Javascript Syntax",
        "school": "Udacity",
        "dates": "May 2016"
    }]
}
```

As was mentioned, make sure to check the errors